# What is the mathematical relationship between hexadecimal colour values on opposite sides of the colour wheel?

Tags: colors, mathematical-optimization, hex

I want to incrementally rotate around the color wheel hopping to the opposite side each turn. I have an undefined number of clients to represent on a kendo chart and I want to ensure that they are all identifiable against their immediate neighbours. Can anyone pin down a mathematical relationship between colours on opposite sides of the colour wheel? I am of course working on this myself but I thought it an interesting little problem that you guys might enjoy with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to do this type of conversion in the HSL or HSV color space, rather than RGB (aka hex values). Then to get the opposite point on the wheel just follow the formula:

```
hue = (hue + 180) % 360
```

So starting with hsl(0, 80%, 20%) would yield hsl(180, 80%, 20%) etc. The easiest way to convert a given RGB value to an RGB value on the opposite point would be to convert RGB to HSL or HSV, do the shift, and convert that back to RGB. The formulas for that can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

**Modern browsers support HSL natively**, so maybe some of this complexity can be avoided and you would never need to muck with RGB values in the first place. http://caniuse.com/css3-colors

Answer (score 1):

The color wheel is based on the [HSV color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), where the hue coordinate represents your angle on the color wheel.  You need to convert RGB colors into HSV, perform your rotation on the hue coordinate, then convert back to RGB.